# change timestamp of packet before sending

Tags: timestamp, packet

I want to know is it possible to change the timestamp of VOIP packet before sending it to network card, or is it possible to change anything in the packet with Virtual NIC?

Comment: It is certainly possible to deep packet inspect and adulterate the content of the data so long as you are in a position of trust (man in the middle) or can assume a position of trust (arp poisoning etc.) so long as the content is unencrypted, or you have access to certificates which are trusted on both ends. This is equally true if you have access to the stack on the host. The question though is why would you want to? what are you trying to accomplish? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to alter packets in term of timestamp, it may be delaying packets at sending side of any open source tool or even change in packet e.g. adding some packets to make a fix size of every packet and removing that extra padding at receiving side.